# Why won't my simple guessing game end, when you've guessed the number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm completely new to programming. I started with the easiest language for newbs, python. I created this simple guess the number game. But my problem is that when you guess the number the script does not end, it just keeps repeating. I would just like to know why. Thank you.

P.S. any other tips would be greatly appreciated, like how to improve the coding. Bare in mind I'm completely new and I don't really know a lot of functions, so be as simple and condescending as possible (I don't mind). Cheers guys!
[ummm... how do i make this more substansive? I wanted to edit the script spacing a bit be it keeps sating it needs to be more substansive so hopefully this extra text makes it more substansive... just ignore this part]

```
import random
running = True

while running:
    guessTaken = 0
    print("Hello! What is your name? ")
    myName = input()

    number = random.randint(0,10)
    print("Well, " +myName+ ", I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10.")
    print("I'll give you 10 guesses, see if you can guess the number I'm thinking of!")

    while guessTaken < 10:
        guess = input("Go on! Take a guess: ")
        guess = int(guess)

        guessTaken += 1

        if number > guess:
            print("Too low!")
        if number < guess:
            print("Too high!")
        if number == guess:
            print("You got it!")
            guessTakenstr = str(guessTaken)
            print("Good job " +myName+ ", you guessed my number in " +guessTakenstr+ " guesses!")
            input("Press <enter> to exit")
            running = False

    if number != guess:
        number = str(number)
        print("Sorry, you've had your 10 goes! The number I was think of was " +number)
        running = False
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct? If not, can you please correct it? Currently according to your indentation you would never come out out `while running:` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the condition

```
while guessTaken < 10:
```

to

```
while (guessTaken < 10) and running:
```

**EDIT**

Adding more explanation.
The `while` loop will check the condition `guessTaken < 10` and keep running for 10 times, irrespective of what your input is (since `guessTaken` is incremented once in the loop). In order to break out of the loop, you either need to add a `break` statement here

```
if number == guess:
        print("You got it!")
        guessTakenstr = str(guessTaken)
        print("Good job " +myName+ ", you guessed my number in "+guessTakenstr+ " guesses!")
        input("Press <enter> to exit")
        running = False
        break # Break statement added
```

or you need to check before entering the loop (again) if the user has given a correct input as in my answer

```
while (guessTaken < 10) and running:
```

Comment: Thanks kampta, this seems to have solved the issue and I think I sort of understand why, but if you have time could you explain why this worked?

Comment: I added more explanation in the answer. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the indentation for your inner while loop is actually correct in your program (that is it is indented 2 spaces inside the `while running:`) loop as -

```
  print("I'll give you 10 guesses, see if you can guess the number I'm thinking of!")

  while guessTaken < 10:
```

Otherwise the program would never even reach the part of guessing the number.

In that case the issue is that in your if part when the number equals the guess, even though you are setting `running=False` , you are not breaking out of the inner while loop , so your program would still go on until you make 10 guesses.

Also, From the program it looks like you really do not need the outer loop , since after 10 guesses you are still exiting out of the loop (so it only runs for one iteration) , if so, you can just remove that loop (The `while running:` loop) altogether and break out of the `while guessTaken < 10:` loop. Example -

```
guessTaken = 0
print("Hello! What is your name? ")
.
.

while guessTaken < 10:
    .
    .
    if number == guess:
        print("You got it!")
        guessTakenstr = str(guessTaken)
        print("Good job " +myName+ ", you guessed my number in " +guessTakenstr+ " guesses!")
        input("Press <enter> to exit")
        break

if number != guess:
    number = str(number)
    print("Sorry, you've had your 10 goes! The number I was think of was " +number)
```

Comment: Thanks Anand, I tried your code but once you guess the number it just repeats the entire script from the start - from the "Hello what is your name" part - Im not sure if its because i entered your script in correctly is there anything that i should have added to it?

Comment: You did not remove the `while running:` loop? Please do read the complete description in the answer as well , and not just copy the code.

Comment: Oh yes Ive done that, and its worked. Thank you. Im still getting to grips with programming. Seems like there are different ways to solve the same problem.

Comment: Yes, most of the times there are countless ways to solve the same problem. :-)